# How do you solve for the positive roots of a function and graph them as points on a plot of the function in mathematica?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, equation

I am attempting to graph the following function and indicate on the plot where the function passes 45 degree slope. I have been able to graph the function itself using the following code:

```
T = 170 Degree;
f[s_, d_] = Normal[Series[Tan[T - (d*s)], {s, 0, 4}]];
r[h_, d_] = Simplify[Integrate[f[s, d], {s, 0, h}]];
a[h_] = Table[r[h, d], {d, 1, 4, .5}];
Plot[a[h], {h, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, -4}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I need to display the point on each curve where the slope exceeds 45 degrees. However, I have thus far been unable to even solve for the numbers, due to something odd about the hadling of tables in the Solve and Reduce functions. I tried:

```
Reduce[{a'[h] == Table[-1, {Dimensions[a[h]][[1]]}], h >= 0}, h]
```

But I apparently can't do this with this kind of function, and I am not sure how to add these results to the plot so that each line gets a mark where it crosses. Does anyone know how to set this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your code, for completeness, with plot parameters slightly modified to zoom into the region of interest:

```
Clear[d,h,T,f,r,a];
T = 170 Degree;
f[s_, d_] = Normal[Series[Tan[T - (d*s)], {s, 0, 4}]];
r[h_, d_] = Simplify[Integrate[f[s, d], {s, 0, h}]];
a[h_] = Table[r[h, d], {d, 1, 4, .5}];

plot = Plot[a[h], {h, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.8}, {0, -0.5}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> {False, True, True, False}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 10], 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.004]}]
```

Here is the code to get the solutions (h-coordinates):

```
In[42]:= solutions = Map[Reduce[{D[#, h] == -1, h >= 0}, h] &, a[h]]

Out[42]= {h == 0.623422, h == 0.415615, h == 0.311711, h == 0.249369, 
   h == 0.207807, h == 0.178121, h == 0.155856}
```

Now produce the plot:

```
points = ListPlot[MapIndexed[{#1, a[#1][[First@#2]]} &, solutions[[All, 2]]], 
         PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.015], Red], 
         PlotRange -> {{0, 0.8}, {0, -0.5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
         Frame -> {False, True, True, False}, 
         FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 10]]
```

Finally, combine the plots:

```
Show[{plot, points}]
```

[image]

Edit:

Responding to the request of cutting plots at the found points -  here is one way:

```
plot = 
 With[{sols  = solutions[[All, 2]]},
  Plot[Evaluate[a[h]*UnitStep[sols - h]], {h, 0, 4}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 0.8}, {0, -0.5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   Frame -> {False, True, True, False}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 10], 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.004]}]]
```

and this should be executed after the solutions have been found.

Comment: @Leonid The definitions of r[] and a[] are done with **=**, instead of **:=** . Is that OK? Results differ ..

Comment: @belisarius: in this case, Set is the right thing to do IMO, since we want to do the simplifications at the definition time, not run-time. Besides making things slower, using SetDelayed here would require that we use something like _?NumericQ on the l.h.s. for the arguments, to avoid error messages. One just has to make sure that d and h have not been defined globally before we run the code. I will add a Clear statement or Block, will update my post in a minute.

Comment: Is there some way to set the curves to stop at the points in question? I have been trying to get the list with the end points to evaluate in the upper limits area of the plot command, but it is refusing to take them in a matching set.

Comment: @Leonid Done. You're now one more in the SO Mma wolfpack

Comment: @Elliot Sorry to say this, but in SO is customary to ask **one** question per "thread". That's because the content is not useful for future reference if you do otherwise. I suggest you to post another question with that!

Comment: @belisarius: thanks, feels much better to be officially inducted. Now I have 1.5 of them - one mine and a half of Daniel's - all the better. I was too quick to answer the OP's request - did not see you comment, sorry about that.

Comment: @Elliot  I updated my post, the answer to your request is at the bottom. But @belisarius is right, it probably should have been another question.

Comment: @Leonid Excellent! I'll send you the first aids manual for the rites of passage

Comment: @Leonid For those `Set` definitions, you might consider using formal variables instead of `Block[{d...}]`.  Formal variables are protected, so someone would have to really go out of there way to define them.  For example, `f[<esc>$d<esc>_, <esc>$s<esc>_] = ...` (where `<esc>` is the escape key,  of course).  Not as easy to read in a SO post, however...

Comment: @WReach  Thanks for the hint, never used them. They may prove useful in some cases indeed. I take it that they get Protected when they are created in the symbol table, right?

Comment: @Leonid They are all predefined empty and protected in the `System` context.

Answer (score 2):

Could find the points via:

```
slope45s = 
 h /. Map[First[Solve[D[#, h] == -1 && h >= 0, h]] &, a[h]]
```

Out[12]= {0.623422, 0.415615, 0.311711, 0.249369, 0.207807, 0.178121, \
0.155856}

Here we put together the list of relevant points.

```
pts = Transpose[{slope45s, Tr[a[slope45s], List]}]
```

Can now plot in any number of ways. Here is one such.

```
p2 = ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, -4}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[.01], Red}];
p1 = Plot[a[h], {h, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, -4}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1];
```

Show[p1, p2]

(Being new to this modern world-- or rather, of an age associated with an earlier civilization-- I do not know how to paste in an image.)

(Okay, thanks Leonid. I think I have an image and also indented code.)

(But why are we talking in parentheses??)

[image]
Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Edit: I did not much like the picture I gave. Here is one I think is more descriptive.

```
makeSegment[pt_, slope_, len_] := 
 Rotate[Line[{pt + {-len/2, 0}, pt + {len/2, 0}}], ArcTan[slope]]

p2 = ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[.01], Red}];
p1 = Plot[a[h], {h, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, -1}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
p3 = Graphics[Map[{Orange, makeSegment[#, -1, .2]} &, pts]];

Show[p1, p2, p3, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: there should be an icon in the set of icons at the top of the editor, for pasting an image. But it may depend on the reputation, I am not sure. I seem to remember that I could not initially post images either. Also, for the code - if you want it to be printed in the "code" font, all it takes is to tab it 4 spaces to the right (tab key itself does not work, so you have to use the space)

Comment: @Daniel It seems you merged two versions of the code (or some statements are missing)

Comment: @belisarius Sorry, you are correct (and worse, I deleted the notebook I had). The list of pts was constructed in a manner similar to Leonid's MapIndexed, but not so elegantly.

Comment: @belisarius How do I transfer that vote? I really am new to this stuff.

Comment: @belisarius et al: Getting back to lessons learned, and forgotten. (1) Don't hit "enter" in posting a comment, unless you are finished. (2) To vote up, or "upvote", just click on the appropriate triangle. (3) To enable that capability, register on stack overflow (which I did). (4) If you don't see new comments explaining all this to you, look for the "show three new comments" icon, or some such. Getting there...

Comment: @Leonid C'mon, Leonid, you know I'll share that welcome message with you.